# what is the difference between main(String a[]) and Main(String a[]) in JAVA?

Tags: java

suppose
we create one java program

```
class abc{
  public Static void main(String a[])
}

class xyz{
  public Static void Main(String a[])
}
```

there is a difference between main() and Main()! Will program compile and run?
will program only compile but not run?

Comment: It's not "JAVA", but "Java", for one.

Comment: Neither will compile.

Comment: main() and Main() both are known as user defined methods since java is a case sensitive language it differs main()  from Main() all the java application must have this main() because by defaultly the execution should be start from main() only if we r not having any mains in our program the static block is executed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you could easily put this in an IDE yourself and try it.

Answer (score 3):

"Will it compile and run?" is left as exercise to the reader.

But to give the explanation of what you will observe: when you want to **invoke** that method from the command line, via

```
 java YourClass
```

then it must be **lowercase** `main()`.

Beyond that: java coding style conventions suggest to use camelCase() for method names. So `Main()` would be bad practice anyway. (for the same reason that your example classes would be named Abc or Xyz - Uppercase for classes!)

Answer (score 0):

Since java is a case sensitive language,

```
class Abc
{
  public Static void main(String a[])
 }

class Xyz
{
   public Static void Main(String a[])
}
```

this code will give compilation  error saying that... expected identifier i.e. `static` not `Static`. Both methods can be in same class i.e.

```
class Abc{ 
 public static void main(String a[]){}
 public static void Main(String a[]){} 
}
```

If you follow naming conventions that will help you to identify by its object name.